# Xcode IOS Lock Some orientation to Portrait and Some to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, portrait

I am working on an application that has about 12 views. I want some to be portrait only and others to be landscape.

How would I go about locking some view's orientation to portrait and others to landscape?

I tried the code below from a previous example, but It does not lock the orientation.

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
 [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost 24 hours of trying I finally fixed the problem. For one "ShouldAutoRotate" never gets called. And thats all I could find everywhere "Just add shouldAutoRotate"... Didnt work. Also i am not sure why people are down voting my question.

What work for me was the add the method below to my Appdelegate.m file.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController){
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

Then add the method below to the viewcontroller.m file I want to be locked to landscape.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: shouldAutoRotate should work if you enable other Interface Orientations in your build settings.

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement `supportedInterfaceOrientation` and `shouldAutorotate` in your ViewController.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

Comment: Hi LucaD,
adding -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations and or -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate. The view still rotates. 
Taken from example here http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-16%E2%80%93Handling-Device-Orientation